# Opposite of jack of all trades master of none

Tags: phrases, phrase-requests

As the title says, what is the opposite of "Jack of all trades master of none"?

Comment: This is too vague. Is this "opposite Jack" master of *all* the trades he plies, or only one? Is he prepared to have a go at anything, or does he only work in one specialised area?

Answer (score 13):

If the opposite is a "Jack of none, master of one (or a few)" then I think the opposite would be a *Specialist*.

If the opposite is "Master of all trades, jack of none", you could use *omnipotent*, as Matt Эллен suggested.

If the opposite in mind is "Jack of none, master of none", you could use *unskilled* or *untrained*. J.R. suggested in a comment that *novice* or *neophyte* could also be used. You could also use *incompetent* but that usually has negative connotations.

Comment: For your second one, it could be omnipotent.

Comment: As Robin Williams said to his son, ["How should I know ? I'm not Buddha.  Go ask your mother; she's omnipotent."](http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=robin+williams+live+at+the+met)

Comment: I like _specialist_ quite a bit for #1, but I like cornbread's suggestion for #2 (_polymath_ or _Renaissance man_). As for #3, a couple more suggestions might be _novice_ or _neophyte_. What I like most about your answer, though, was how you broke it up into three possible ways to form an antonym ~ nicely done.

Answer (score 6):

*Renaissance man* or *[polymath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymath)*.

> A **polymath** (Greek: πολυμαθής, polymathēs, "having learned much")[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymath) is
>   a person whose expertise spans a significant number of different
>   subject areas.
>
> The common term **Renaissance man** is used to describe a person who
>   is well educated or who excels in a wide variety of subjects or
>   fields.[3] The concept emerged from the numerous great thinkers of
>   that era who excelled in multiple fields of the arts and science,
>   including Leonardo da Vinci, Michelangelo, Galileo Galilei, Copernicus
>   and Francis Bacon; the emergence of these thinkers was likewise
>   attributed to the then rising notion in Renaissance Italy expressed by
>   one of its most accomplished representatives, Leon Battista Alberti
>   (1404–1472): that "a man can do all things if he will."

Comment: A fine answer indeed! It really depends on whether the "anti-JOAT" is good at one or many things.

Comment: Antijoat. This is a great coined term. Who cares what it means.

Comment: Just the antithesis of "Jack Of All Trades". Point is: is he a Master of one, or Master of all? Because I'm sure a renaissance man can't be, for example, an expert on every field of Computer Science, Physics and Mathematics.

Answer (score 0):

You could also think of an *expert* on a topic, a *master* in some skill, because he's probably too focused on his subject to achieve that level of mastery in a second skill.